# Function to add custom HTML into head in custom post-type list page

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, customization, admin, editor

[image]

How can I add custom HTML/PHP file into head where custom post-type list showing like this ?

Any Wordpress function can do this ? or I can only do by JS(jQuery) to append my custom content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its okey you can hook into `admin_notices`. Like this:

Change `post_type` to the real `post_type` name.. I assumed it would be "program".

```
function wpse_76471_add_html() {
    global $pagenow ,$post;

    if( $post->post_type == 'program' && $pagenow == 'edit.php' ) {

        $output = '<div class="my-div">';
            $output .= '<h2>'. __('My custom content (HTML/PHP)', 'program') .'</h2>';
        $output .= '</div>';

        echo $output;
    }
}
add_action('admin_notices','wpse_76471_add_html');
```

The div will be above the title... Hope its okay. 
Maybe there is another hook you can use: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Administrative_Filters